# Eclipse debugging getting full stack

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I just have a simple question, consider the following method

```
public void do_something(long arg){
//some work
}
```

and in eclipse, I added a break point for the above method and run the program, everything is fine, but I cannot find out the stack of current point?! for example

```
call do_something
push id
call previous_method
call xyz
pop z
call useZ
push z
```

I mean this method is called by 10 different methods and different stack, how would I find out the full stack of the thread(including methods) with eclipse?! should I change some default property or what?!

Comment: Have you seen the Debug View? There are all threads and the thread with the current call stack. Edit: And actual parameters (arguments) of the methods you can find in the Variables View. You can click on any method in the call stack in der Debug View and the Variables View shows you alle actual parameters and local variables of the selected method.

Comment: Yes of course I change the perspective, I know that a method is called by another one, but in debug mode, it just shows the called method

Answer (score 2):

To put an image, I repeat my comment as an answer.

In the Debug View you can find the call stack and in the Variables View you can find the actual parameters and values of the local variables:

[image: Call Stack for a single threaded application]

To get the actual parameters and values of local variables of an other method in the call stack just click in the Debug View on a method above the current method.

This isn't working for a multi-threaded application. You can only see the call stack for the current thread where the method is running in it. Look at:
[image: Call Stack for a multi threaded application]

In the method `foo` a thread is created by creating a timer. If the jvm suspend on `bar`, it only sees the call stack of `TimerTask.run`  -> `bar` but not `main` -> `foo` -> `run` -> `bar`.

Comment: perfect dude, but I really don't get the full stack, I think some calls are from new threads, so I see the thread stack, and the problem is that the thread which created the new thread is no exists no longer after its call, in other word I want the global method call history

Comment: Yes, thats a problem. For this I think @Robin Green is right that you have to look for a logging framework maybe in combination with AOP. I hope there is a simpler solution for it, becouse debugging of multi threaded apps is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

What you've described **isn't a stack.**

It's a history.

Eclipse isn't designed to give you a history. However, there are other tools that can show you the history, such as Chronon. However, that might be too expensive for you! It also might use too much memory if your application is very complex.

The simplest way to get a history, however, is to put `System.out.println("some message")` in lots of places.

It can be inconvenient to use System.out.println everywhere, so a couple of other ideas have been developed to improve on this:

1. Logging frameworks handle common tasks such as printing the time when something happened, rotating big log files etc.
2. Aspect-oriented programming allows you to inject logging in lots of places at once.

Comment: The problem is, I'm working on a project which has developed before, and many calls are using system and events, so printing in everywhere is kinda impossible, it's to mass complex

Comment: do you mean Aspect Oriented Programming?! any link please. and the Chronon is really unfair for me, paying for finding a simple call history(open source application)!

Comment: Oh, you have an open source application! That's interesting, care to share a link to it? How about this - you share a link to your open source application, I'll share a link to an Aspect Oriented Programming site. Fair's fair.

Comment: Fair, but I'm not only the person work on the project, the project is hosted in a private repository, the number of users for the start is limited, I really cannot provide anything, but all would say is that a part of project is kinda customized apache tapestry project.

Comment: doesn't sound very open source to me

Comment: I know, so do you except we share the work while we haven't coded even 10%?!

Comment: So is your real problem "I don't understand how Apache Tapestry works and I want to see what methods are called in what order to better understand how it works"?

Comment: this is not for tapestry really, we have stuck in somewhere else, the problem is methods are called by threads, and we cannot find out the thread caused the invocation.

Comment: How is the invocation happening? Is the thread long running and it reads messages off a queue or something like that, or is the thread started specifically to do this action?

Comment: sorry for late reply mate, well I just see many threads are created, and each stack has the `Runnable#run()` method at the end of the stack as expected, maybe I asked the question wrong, but you are right I need the calling history inside a mass codez!

Comment: It's difficult to provide a better answer without more detail. Anyway here is the link on AOP http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting.html